# How to use <Form.List /> (or something similar) in 'formik-antd'?

Tags: reactjs, antd, formik

I got simple question - Is it possible to use <Form.List /> in formik-antd? Tryed to find info about it but can't find anything in 3 hours. I need add dynamic fields in form, want to use <Form.List /> like in antd, but i use 'formik-antd'. looks like in 'formik-antd' no Form.List.. :( only Form.Item.

Any one know is the 'formik-antd' got <Form.List /> or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

`formik-antd` is only used to make the components of `antd` compatible with formik, but something like `Form.List` isn't something that will be in `formik-antd`, but it comes from formik.

What you should use is [`FieldArray`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray).

Example from docs:

[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-fieldarray-example-echqg).

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray } from 'formik';

// Here is an example of a form with an editable list.
// Next to each input are buttons for insert and remove.
// If the list is empty, there is a button to add an item.
export const FriendList = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Friend List</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ friends: ['jared', 'ian', 'brent'] }}
      onSubmit={values =>
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }, 500)
      }
      render={({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray
            name="friends"
            render={arrayHelpers => (
              <div>
                {values.friends && values.friends.length > 0 ? (
                  values.friends.map((friend, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                      <Field name={`friends.${index}`} />
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)} // remove a friend from the list
                      >
                        -
                      </button>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={() => arrayHelpers.insert(index, '')} // insert an empty string at a position
                      >
                        +
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  ))
                ) : (
                  <button type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push('')}>
                    {/* show this when user has removed all friends from the list */}
                    Add a friend
                  </button>
                )}
                <div>
                  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          />
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: "formik-antd is only used to make the components of antd compatible with formik"  -  thats exactly what i need. I got form full of antd components, and i should use it with formik and yup. So I need formik-antd component for array of fields (inputs)

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same Issue. My solution was to simply change the name in the import statement, just like so:

```
import {Form as antdForm} from 'antd';
```